# generate_series for every hour in hh24:mi:ss format

Tags: amazon-redshift

i have a generate series of every minute for the whole 24 hours. how about a generate _series showing every hour only in hh24:mi:ss and hh24:mi format.

result should be

00:00
01:00
02:00
      :
      :
23:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT to_char(generate_series(0, 23) * interval '1 hour' + '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, 'HH24:MI')
```

will return:

```
00:00
01:00
02:00
03:00
...
23:00
```

Just modify the format string for what you desire.