# How to generate_series of every hour of every day of 1 year from the current timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a query that generates every day of the year(shown below). What if I want to get a series of every hour of every day of the year from the current timestamp. Example: today is July 23,2019 10:30:00 AM, the result I am hoping to get is below

```
2019-07-23 20:30:00
2019-07-23 20:00:00
2019-07-23 19:00:00
2019-07-23 18:00:00
.
.
.
2018-07-23 20:00:00
```

This is a Redshift (PostgreSQL 8.0.2) query for Eclipse Birt. Hoping to create a parameter for both date and time but seems difficult to achieve if 2 separate ranges.

```
select cast(convert_timezone('UTC','AEST',cast(now() as timestamp without time zone)) as date) - generate_series(0, 365) date, 
to_char(cast(convert_timezone('UTC','AEST',cast(now() as timestamp without time zone)) as date) - generate_series(0, 365), 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_disp;
```

Example: today is July 23,2019 10:30:00 AM, the result I am hoping to get is below:

```
2019-07-23 20:30:00
2019-07-23 20:00:00
2019-07-23 19:00:00
2019-07-23 18:00:00
.
.
.
2018-07-23 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57154668/174777).

Use:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', now()::timestamp) - generate_series(0, 24 * 365) * interval '1 hour'
```

This outputs:

```
2019-07-23 05:00:00
2019-07-23 04:00:00
etc
```

Comment: yes. i'm not good at this and have tried. I have no time now and needed this urgently. Thanks. Will get this soon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DATEADD** Redshift function, using "h", "hr" or "hrs" as your first parameter. Documentation for this function can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html).